# Submenu same width in Flatsome Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have problem with my submenu in Flatsome Wordpress. I try my best to edit width of this submenu to have same width with main menu (range from logo to red button) but no results. Anyone can help me, please. Thank you so much :((
[Here is my website](http://nhakhoaquoctekay.com/)

Comment: add code which you tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

@alien
Here is main menu I want to edit width of submenu

[Main menu Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpwNg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Flatsome is notorious for having too many selectors in their css, making it hard to override. Here's what I'm using, and it works:

```css
/*Sets width of dropdown menus*/
#header .nav-dropdown {
    width: 95vw;
}
```

You'll want to enter whatever width you desire, of course. Also, if you have other menus that you don't want this to apply to (for example, a top bar menu item that has a submenu), you can add a class to the top-level menu items you want this snippet to apply to in the WP menu editor and add that class to the css above.

Example: add class 'wide-dropdown' to each top-level menu item (not submenu items underneath it), then the css would be...

```css
#header .wide-dropdown .nav-dropdown {
        width: 95vw;
    }
```

Hopefully that helps!